# Getting Forbidden Error on " dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven"

Tags: android, maven, bintray

Could not HEAD 'https://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven/com/mindorks/android/prdownloader/0.5.0/prdownloader-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

This project was working properly but when i update my Android Studio to 4.2.2 then got this Error.

[image: Here is my build.gradle file]

Kindly help me out

Comment: You will need access credentials to access the specified location.

Comment: I don't think that will help because of this: https://www.infoq.com/news/2021/02/jfrog-jcenter-bintray-closure/

Comment: any possible solution or any alternate of jcenter?

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with version 0.4.0, you can download it from the default repo. More information here:

- https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.mindorks.android
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mindorks.android/prdownloader